# Divide array of CGFloats into n subArrays such that the sum of each is as close to equal keeping order

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to break an array of CGFloats into subarrays that are close to equal to the average of the sum divided by chunks needed. I have looked for even the name of an algorithm to study that does this but have come up empty. I have to keep the order of the numbers as they represent views.

Assume we have a list of CGFloats

```
let chunks : [CGFloat] = [49.00000000000001, 24.776, 18.432, 50.776, 29.208, 40.89600000000001, 47.984, 33.656, 42.656, 64.208, 44.432, 24.776, 33.656, 44.432, 56.984, 23.88, 70.0]
```

I currently have a function that divides the chunks up into subarrays to attempt to make them as equal as possible.

```
func divideUp(chunkCount:Int,totalSumOverride:CGFloat? = nil, tokens:[CGFloat])->[[CGFloat]]{
        
        var chunks_yielded = 0
       
        let total_sum = tokens.reduce(0) { (a, b) -> CGFloat in
            return a + b
        }
        //print("the total sum \(total_sum)")
        var avg_sum = total_sum/CGFloat(chunkCount)
        
       // print("the avg \(avg_sum)")
        var chunks = [[CGFloat]]()
        var chunksum : CGFloat = 0
        var sum_of_seen : CGFloat = 0
        var chunk = [CGFloat]()
        
        for i in 0..<tokens.count{
            let token = tokens[i]
            let item = token

            if chunkCount - chunks_yielded == 1{
               // print("yielding out \(i) \(sum_of_seen)")
                for x in i..<tokens.count{
                    let t = tokens[x]
                    chunk.append(t)
                }
                chunks.append(chunk)
                break
            }
            
            let to_yield = chunkCount - chunks_yielded
            let chunks_left = (tokens.count) - i

            if to_yield > chunks_left{
                //print("executing chunks left")
                if chunk.isEmpty == false{
                    chunks.append(chunk)
                }
                
                
                for x in i..<tokens.count{
                    let c = [tokens[x]]
                    //let t = tokens[x]
                    chunks.append(c)
                    
                }
                
                break
            }
            sum_of_seen += item
            if chunksum < avg_sum{
                chunk.append(token)
                chunksum += item
            }else{
                avg_sum = (total_sum - sum_of_seen)/CGFloat((to_yield - 1))
                chunks_yielded += 1
                chunksum = item
                chunks.append(chunk)
                chunk = [token]
            }
        }
        return chunks
    }
```

This works pretty well and credit to (@timgeb) from a python post.  This is close to the desired output. For example

```
let better = divideUp(chunkCount: 6, tokens: chunks)
print("better \(better)")
//output [[49.00000000000001, 24.776, 18.432, 50.776], [29.208, 40.89600000000001, 47.984], [33.656, 42.656, 64.208], [44.432, 24.776, 33.656], [44.432, 56.984], [23.88, 70.0]]
```

But there are cases where it does not work well for example a count of 7

```
let grouped = divideUp(chunkCount: 7, tokens: chunks)
print("group \(grouped)")
// output [[49.00000000000001, 24.776, 18.432, 50.776], [29.208, 40.89600000000001, 47.984], [33.656, 42.656, 64.208], [44.432, 24.776], [33.656, 44.432], [56.984], [23.88, 70.0]]
```

Is there a way to improve this to be more accurate or is there a way to balance the Array sums after they have been produced that would make them more smooth?  I have seen a built in partition function but I cannot see that it will do what I need.

Comment: This is a version of the bin packing (or "backpack") problem. There are various algorithms for attacking it, but its complexity is NP-hard and so there is no "efficient' solution (one that scales in polynomial time as N increases) that will be optimal. For reasonably small values of N, you'll either use a heuristic like this one that is fast, but may not be optimal, or do an exhaustive search, which can be extremely slow for non-trivial sizes of N. This algorithm is probably as good as you'll get without doing some amount of search, which is much more complex. Search "Branch and bound."

Comment: Rob, thank you so much. Do you suggest I close this or leave it open?  I really don't know the protocol but you gave me as much info as I could hope for at the moment

Comment: How is the total permutation count calculated? It seems to me that a good solution would be to spread that space evenly across the thread space of a compute kernel, with each result being the average error. Then, you'd take the index for the minimum result, and perform the same array-divvying in Swift as you did in Metal.

Comment: The Views hold text so I know the intrinsic size of it with a specific font. I use the aspect ratio of the bounding area to know the best way to lay it out keeping it as uniform as possible. This is the chunk count. I start the process above. I think your comment is more in line with what Rob suggests as well as what you suggest in creating partition indexes and redistributing based on a best and worst result. Finally busting out without an improvement or total count is exceeded. I like this but I think I would want a few extra rules like last chunk can never be wider than first chunk.

Comment: Would it in theory be best to use the greedy method above to create the partition indexes before comparing?

Comment: Last question I have would be is there a need to save the steps you take while refining?  I could see a situation that the rules cause you to go done one path then the rules would revert back to where you were and then it would just keep doing and undoing that for a count.  Such could happen if the previous chunk and next chunk after a problem chunk are really close in size.  Is it typical to save a struct of steps so that if you keep hitting the same step you try the opposite once?